# How to make the new facebook post embed feature responsive?

Tags: css, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I couldn't find any solutions on google which can make the newly introduced facebook posts embed to responsive. Does anyone got a solution or tricks? Thanks

```
<div id="fb-root"></div> <script>(function(d, s, id) { var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]; if (d.getElementById(id)) return; js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id; js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"; fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs); }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<div class="fb-post" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-security/national-cyber-security-awareness-month/10151630123500766" ><div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-security/national-cyber-security-awareness-month/10151630123500766">Post</a> by <a href="https://www.facebook.com/security">Facebook Security</a>.</div></div>
```

Comment: can you comment more ?

Comment: hello @PooyaEstakhri i've edit my post, try creating a new html file and insert the code above, it is not responsive for mobile view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**If you mean "responsive" as in "responsive design",** you can't. Facebook uses a cross-domain iframe for JS/CSS isolation and session security, and it generates the iframe dimensions dynamically based on contents using privileged cross-domain communication, so you can't just play around with CSS to get things how you want them. See this section on [official page for the social plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-posts/):

```
Can I customize how the post is displayed on my web page?

Currently, you cannot customize how Embedded Posts are displayed on your page. The size of the post is fixed to the same dimensions as it's shown on Facebook.
```

**If you mean that the plugin is not displaying properly,** you should follow the instructions with the **Get Code** button on the [official page for the social plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-posts/).

*Details:*

Your markup is missing an app ID. Where did you find this markup? You need to specify an app ID. If you load the JS SDK manually, that means adding it to the parameters of `FB.init` [as seen here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/). In your case, you are using the shortened URL-based init, where the SDK URL has parameters in its fragment: `#xfbml=1` in your example. You will need to change it so it is more like `#xfbml=1&appId=1234567890`.

**Update:** You should use the console in your browser's built-in developer tools (or Firebug, etc.) to see info about errors with the JS SDK. When I tried your code on an https:// site, I got this error:

```
[blocked] The page at https:// ran insecure content from http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js.
```

so I changed the URL from `http://connect.facebook.net/...` to a protocol-relative URL: `//connect.facebook.net/...`

Another option would have been to just try on an http:// site only. At that point, I got the following errors:

```
Invalid App Id: Must be a number or numeric string representing the application id.
FB.getLoginStatus() called before calling FB.init().
```

This confirms my suspicion -- you need an app ID. I added an app ID and it works.

Comment: "... you can't. Facebook uses a cross-domain iframe for JS/CSS isolation and session security..." Not a good excuse. Instagram uses an iframe and they're able to resize their embeds just fine. Facebook can't because they put fixed widths all over the place

Comment: It's technically impossible. The only way to enable you, the embedder, to change the content inside the iframe would be to utilize some cross-domain communication channel via JS. They do this in some cases -- they just don't provide as many hooks as people might want.

Comment: @kdubb is right. Twitter embeds also scale just fine within a min- and max- width of their own setting. Facebook can do this, it is possible, and I really wish they would.

Answer (score 23):

Set `data-width` to `auto` to use fluid width:

`<div class="fb-post" data-href="url" data-width="auto"></div>`

Comment: The documentation on developers.facebook.com says "Leave empty to use fluid width.", but that didn't work, `auto` did. Thanks!

Comment: This is a correct solution, but the the image/thumbnail from a post will look fubar. Try to test it with an image in the post: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-posts#

Comment: Hmm, wrong documentation from Facebook, tut tut!!
Unfortunately as mentioned above, it makes the images in posts look bad. 
Is there an option to not display post images in embedded posts? Checked Facebook docs but how can we trust them ever again?! ;)

Comment: This should be marked as right answer

Answer (score 18):

I've created a small jQuery plugin to fix this. Since the Facebook Embedded Posts plugin renders the correct width when using the `data-width` attribute, we can listen for width changes on our page, update the `data-width` attributes and then re-render the plugins.

See http://jsfiddle.net/brohde/GRcen/

Usage: `$('#post').autoResizeFbPost();`

*Plugin logic:*

- On document ready:

  - Save original HTML of `$('#post')` to preserve any `<div class="fb-post">` elements – the Facebook SDK removes this from the DOM.
- *The Fix:* Update all `<div class="fb-post">` elements with the correct `data-width` attribute (Uses `$('#post').width()` ).
- On window resize, run *The Fix* again and also call `FB.XFBML.parse();` to render the Facebook plugin(s). The plugin will wait 1 second after the last window resize to avoid multiple DOM updates and `FB.XFBML.parse();` calls.

Comment: I was able to get this sorta working, but it keeps on refreshing, constantly.  In the flash, before it refreshes again, I can see that the iframe is the correct size...

Comment: @DougCassidy `<div id="post">` should surround only fb-post div and not all fb javascript stuff. Did the same mistake.

Answer (score 3):

Found it frustrating I couldn't find anything more elegant than utilizing overflow and max-width 100% to force a horizontal scrollbar.

Added - `style="overflow-x: auto; max-width: 100%;"`

To result in the following fb-post portion of the embed;

`<div class="fb-post" style="overflow-x: auto; max-width: 100%;" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=406800492780796&amp;set=a.202870829840431.42585.202866106507570&amp;type=1" data-width="550">`

If you want a little more elegance can always implement styling on the scrollbar.

CSS Webkit Scrollbars - http://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/

jQuery Tiny Scrollbar - http://baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/

Hope someone finds this useful.

Comment: Adding the styles to the `fb-post` div itself didn't work for me, but adding it to a wrapper div around it did the trick, e.g. `<div class="fb-post-wrapper" style="overflow-x: auto; max-width: 100%;"><div class="fb-post" ...></div></div>`

Answer (score 0):

If yours posts are video, you can use Embed Videos instead of Embed Posts, they are responsive. You can get all others datas from open graph and create your own design.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-video-player

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution.  Please [edit] to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.