# how to make the facebook post embed (iframe version) responsive?

Tags: facebook, css, responsive-design, responsive, facebook-iframe

As long as you embed facebook photos (i'm talking only about the iframe version in this context) the solution described in [Embedding facebook post on responsive website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39068479/embedding-facebook-post-on-responsive-website) is fine.

But the quesion is: how to make a real facebook post embed responsive? example iframe:

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/post.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fmashable.tech%2Fposts%2F10153931394037919&width=500" width="500" height="482" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

please note: i'm not able to use the JavaScript-SDK version, have to use the iframe.

Comment: Having the same problem too. This is for a facebook post embed not a video post embed.

Comment: You'll find no solution for this issue. You have to use the FB Javascript SDK

Comment: @michbeck can you detail a little more? I am also struggling with the same issue (facebook post embed) for the last 2 hours. :D

Comment: @NadaLeCoupanec as far as i know the FB javascript sdk is still the only option you can use

Comment: Thank you! I ended up making everything scrollable: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19650278/10619827

Answer (score 0):

What about a jQuery solution?

```
jQuery( window ).on( "load resize", function () {
    jQuery( 'iframe[src*="facebook.com"]' ).each(function() {

        /* get width of parent element */
        var width = Math.round( jQuery( this ).parent().width() );
        if ( width > 500 ){ width = 500; } else if ( width < 180 ){ width = 180; };

        /* replace width value in iframe src */
        var src = new URL( jQuery( this ).attr( "src" ) );
        src.searchParams.set( "width", width );

        /* append new width */
        jQuery( this ).attr( "src", src );
        jQuery( this ).attr( "width", width );

    });
});
```

This script gets the width of the parent element and adjusts the iframe accordingly.